# What's the best way to thank Math Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I am currently taken a real analysis course, and the thought occurred to me, "I have learned more about analysis on Math Stack Exchange than I have sitting through analysis lectures." And I feel grateful. I have been trying to give back by answering questions where I can and editing posts - I've even told a few people about MSE -- but I wonder, what's the best way to thank Math Stack Exchange?

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just stick around here and answer the questions of people who are newer to math; e.g., other people who are starting with analysis.

Comment: And, if possible, answer some of the questions in the "Unanswered" queue.  We'd love to get all of the questions on the site answered eventually.  :)

Comment: And also help "clean up", by reviewing posts in review queues, flagging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the best way to thank Math Stack Exchange is **answering** questions or **mentioning** MSE in the Acknowledge of your thesis.

There are other, good ways, to thank Math Stack Exchange which is making it a better place:

- editing questions
- flagging inappropriate content
- giving useful comments
- upvoting questions and answers
- Visiting this site https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ every once in a while...
- Helping  the community grow (so more Mathematicians here, more students, more knowledge, more Mathematics, more happiness :)

For the last bullet, you could promoting through twitter or fb for example.

Also you can do it by communicating directly with the students, not necessarily mathematicians nor university students.

Or wearing clothes with the MSE logo; 
a hoodie with the MSE logo or a shirt or something like that.